# Why does findstr also search in files outside specified directory?

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-7, findstr

There is a simple behavior of **findstr** that I do not understand on Windows 7.

I run a batch file in administrator mode (if not, they simply do not launch) with the following script in several different locations:

```
@echo off
set local=%~dp0
echo %local%
REM to check that I am where I think I am
findstr /s /i /c:"stringtofind" %local%*.ext
```

When I run this script from a location in `"C:\Program files\~"` or `"C:\Program files (x86)\~"` the output includes .ext files outside the `%local%` directory and sub-directories with `"stringtofind"`. Actually all the matching files are on the hard disk.

This behavior does not appear in every other location I could test (anywhere else in a C:\ directory basically) where only the matching file in the directory and sub-directories appear.

Is there something specific to the `Program files` directories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing to

```
findstr /s /i /c:"stringtofind" "%local%*.ext"
```

In the cases you mention, the directoryname contains spaces, so `findstr` is finding multiple arguments. "Using the quotes" groups "strings containing spaces" into one string.

Comment: That is exactly what's happening, thank you for the resolution!